# How do I grant the Facebook reviewer permission to use my app?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm developing a web site that uses FB login and the `user_friends` permission. I have submitted the review but It was rejected as the reviewer got the following message:

> "App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't
>   have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app
>   admin for permissions."

How do I grant the reviewer permission to use my app? I thought on changing to Live mode instead of on development but I'm not sure and I don't want to be rejected again.

Comment: You should not have to grant them anything, the reviewers have accounts to test apps that are not restricted in those regards, like normal user accounts are. Or did you explicitly tell them to use any specific account in your review instructions? This sounds like the person reviewing your app simply messed it up.

Comment: @04FS I just sent it again and this time they could test it.